# Could a airship be built using vacuum as the lighter-than-air “material”?

Tags: aircraft-physics, aerospace-materials, lighter-than-air

Could an airship be built that uses instead of a very light gas a vacuum to keep it floating? Or would the materials needed to keep its volume even without the pressure from the inside always be heavier than the lift by the vacuum could handle?

Comment: Sure, if materials science is no object.

Comment: Maybe some day someone will develop an envelope made of graphene or something that is light enough and able to sustain the 14 psi implosion pressure.

Comment: Vacuum is much cheaper than helium, vacuum can also be manufactured on the launch site or onboard the airship. It is really a pity that it is impossible to make a  hull that is lighter than the helium fill that we are replacing and can withstand the external pressure.

Comment: @Penguin this is not how physics works. Vacuum is lighter than any material. By definition. Because it has no mass.

Comment: @Florian. No, the mistake I made was understanding the relationship between weight and buoyancy, I assumed a vacuum created no  buoyancy force, but that is wrong.